# Intellij IDEA. Adding Files from some folder to the project

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to add some files form a directory to an IDEA project ?
I do not want to add all the directory because it is huge and it will slow down the app.
And 2-nd - is it possible to tell IDEA to not add all subdirectories from some folder but only the files it contains ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out than one good option is to right click folders in the IDE and select the option "Mark directory as" -> Excluded. It dissapears from the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If there are files or folders that you don't wish to be part of your project, my advice would be to not include them in your IntelliJ project in the first place.

If you're talking about source files, you can individually mark which directories are source and test; simply right click and "mark as source".

If you have hundred of source files that aren't needed, I'd wonder why they exist in the first place.  No dependencies at all?  You can safely ignore them?  Then remove them from the project.

If you do have dependencies, but don't need to modify the files, perhaps they should be in a separate JAR that you add to the project.

Or just leave all of it.  IntelliJ is fast enough.  Don't make a solution for a problem that doesn't exist.  Run IntelliJ on a machine with sufficient memory and you'll be fine.

Comment: Let's say I have a folder named folder1, inside this folder I have 1000 files. I need to import in my project 10 of them. Could I achieve this ?

Comment: I don't know how or why.  Don't put those files into the project in the first place.  Check out only what you need from your source code management system.  If you don't need them, why are they there?  Put the code under source code management and remove what you don't need.

Comment: It's a legacy project with a lot of stuff generated during build time.

Comment: Then generate them with every build.  Why are you keeping them if they're generated?

Comment: Ok, there are more details I can't explain here. I just was wondering maybe there is such a feature. Thank you .